# Show command queue is not active

Tags: pycharm

I am using the latest version in Pyrcharm, but I have a problem. The "Show command queue" does not seem to be active / working:

[image]

Any idea how I can fix this ? I looked at the settings but with no luck.

I am using Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl-Alt-S > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Activate 'Command queue for Python Console